# VS C# app batch build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, batch-processing

When I use batch build in VS2008, I can see in its output window the csc.exe batch command statement.
Then I copy that string into CMD inside the Solution main directory 
It works but keeps silent. No errors no warning, just "Microsoft All rights reserved", and no exe module is generated.

What's the matter? what's wrong?

C:\SatServer>c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /platform:x
86 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /reference:bin\Debug\CommonClass.dll /reference:b
in\Debug\DBManager.dll /reference:bin\Debug\Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.Dialog.dll /reference:bin\De
bug\Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.dll /reference:bin\Debug\State.dll /reference:c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.N
ET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.configuration.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\M
icrosoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft
\Framework\v3.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.
0.50727\System.Data.dll /reference:c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Deployment.d
ll /reference:c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /reference:c:\WINDOWS\Microso
ft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll /reference:c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50
727\System.Management.dll /reference:c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Fo
rms.dll /reference:c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /reference:"C:\Progr
am Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /fil
ealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\SatServer.exe /resource:obj\Debug\SatServer.Cli.resources /reso
urce:obj\Debug\SatServer.ServerForm.resources /resource:obj\Debug\SatServer.Properties.Resources.res
ources /resource:SQLCommands_Old_SelectExamQuestions.sql,SatServer.SQLCommands._Old_SelectExamQuest
ions.sql /resource:SQLCommands\InsertExam.sql,SatServer.SQLCommands.InsertExam.sql /resource:SQLComm
ands\InsertExamQuestionListDetails.sql,SatServer.SQLCommands.InsertExamQuestionListDetails.sql /reso
urce:SQLCommands\InsertExamQuestionList.sql,SatServer.SQLCommands.InsertExamQuestionList.sql /resour
ce:SQLCommands\GetExamId.sql,SatServer.SQLCommands.GetExamId.sql /resource:SQLCommands\GetExamQuesti
onListId.sql,SatServer.SQLCommands.GetExamQuestionListId.sql /resource:SQLCommands\SelectExamQuestio
ns.sql,SatServer.SQLCommands.SelectExamQuestions.sql /resource:Activation\Activation.exe,SatServer.A
ctivation.Activation.exe /target:winexe /win32icon:ikey.ico Cli.cs Cli.Designer.cs LOCALCLASSBOX\Leg
al.cs LOCALCLASSBOX\LocalBox.cs ServerCommunicator.cs ServerForm.cs ServerForm.Designer.cs Program.c
s Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs Properties\Settings.Designer.cs

result:
Microsoft Compiler(R) Visual C# 2008 version 3.5.30729.1
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 3.5
(C) Microsoft Corp.. All rights reserved

Comment: What do you have in your CMD exactly?

Comment: Where are you looking for the executable?  The command line says it should be placed in "obj\Debug\SatServer.exe".  It won't be in the current directory.